# Unable to Build/Run Multiple Frameworks Using VS 2017's Csproj

Tags: visual-studio-2017, csproj

I'm using the [JavaScript Services](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) Angular infrastructure to build an Angular project that utilizes Entity Framework. I was able to produce a similar project in the past by modifying the project.json file but project settings are now set in the csproj file in VS2017. Below is my code based on [Microsoft's recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj) for adapting project.json files to csproj:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework> <-- Tried with and without ths line -->
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1;net452</TargetFrameworks>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452'">
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp1.1'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
...
```

On Build I get the following error referencing several files in my project:

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

With the `<TargetFramework>` tag removed, no netcoreapp1.1 references were found.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? `dotnet --version` should tell

Comment: Also note that you probably want to be using `SDK="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"` for asp.net core apps

Comment: Thanks for the reply... The dotnet version is 1.0.2 and I'm actually using `SDK=Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"`.